# Dropdownlist(ddlState) value loss when acess in Javascript after AsyncPostBackTrigger in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

I have ddlCountry dropdownlist and ddlState dropdownlist. ddlState is in update panel. On selection of country I have populated its states using the selectedindexchanged event of ddlCountry. I have added start value "-1" to both dropdown after bind, and I check in Javascript if dropdownlist content is [Select] value "-1" then alert and return false.

But Validation is proper for ddlCountry and for ddlState its value becomes "blank" after ajax update panel fires and validation fail.

How should i resolve them? I dont know why the ddlState value is lost after AsyncPostBackTrigger.

```
  //javascript validation

        function validateForm()
                {
                    if (ddlCountry .value == "-1")
                    {
                        alert("Country  should not be blank.");
                        ddlCountry .focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (ddlState .value == "-1")
                    {
                        alert("State should not be blank.");
                        ddlState .focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
        //Aspx code
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry " runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" Width="207px"
                                AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry _SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelState" runat="server">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>                               
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState " runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" Width="177px">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                    </Triggers>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            //Code Behind

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                    BindCountry();
                    }
            }
            protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {       
                    int countryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value);

                    ifcountryID == -1)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    strSQL = @"SELECT State_ID,State_Desc
                                FROM State_Master 
                                WHERE countryID = '" + countryID + @"';

                    DataTable dataTableState = null;
                    dataTableState = objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDatasetQuery(strSQL).Tables[0];

                    var dictioneryState = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                    foreach(DataRow dr in dataTableStudy.Rows)
                    {
                        dictioneryState .Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["State_ID"]), dr["State_Desc"].ToString());
                    }

                    ddlState.DataTextField = "Value";
                    ddlState.DataValueField = "Key";
                    ddlState.DataSource = dictioneryState;
                    ddlState.DataBind();
                    ddlState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[Select]", "-1"));
                    ddlState.Items[0].Selected = true;          

                }
```

Comment: both ddl must be inside updatepanel

Comment: i m binding on selectedindechanged event of ddlCountry only.....ddlState dropdown value checking in javascript if it is "-1" then generate alert..when i check value in javascript it showing me blank value ""...but when i use Postbacktrigger for ddlState value is getting in javascript and all work is fine...but smoothness of page using async is better than Postbacktrigger...thts y i use async trigger...My main problem is ddlState  value is not getting in javascript when i use async trigger but using Postback trigger value is getting......

Answer (score 0):

Enable viewstate to true for both dropdown list like below:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState " runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" Width="177px" EnableViewState=true>                                                     </asp:DropDownList>
```

It might solve your problem.

Thanks